# Postgres Adding Month to date

Tags: postgresql, datetime

In postgresql 10

`select '2019-02-28'::timestamp + interval '1 months'`

resulted to: **2019-03-28 00:00:00**

It was supposed to return **2019-03-31 00:00:00**

How to get actual result?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see Postgres is giving the correct answers; adding one month to 2019-02-28 should result in 2019-03-28 in the same way that adding one month to 2019-02-27 should result in 2019-03-27. In these cases you are asking PostgreSQL to add one month to a specific date and it is doing this. Things do get interesting when you try something like `select '2019-01-30'::timestamp + interval '1 months'` (result `2019-02-28 00:00:00`) but that's really the only logical choice (because 2019-02-30 is not valid).

I'm assuming that your real question is "given a timestamp, how do I get the last day in the following month"; if so try something like:

`SELECT (date_trunc('MONTH', '2019-02-28'::timestamp) + INTERVAL '2 MONTH - 1 day');`

Note: If you are using this in a query then you are probably better to get the first day of the following month so your query can say `where xxx > month1 and xxx < followingmonth` (otherwise you end up losing the last days data).

Comment: Yeah. The idea of '1 week' is fairly well-defined; it always has 7 days. (Allow me a little hand-waving here. I've seen things . . .) But '1 month' is not as well-defined; it might actually have between 28 and 31 days. Some businesses make their own rules. I've seen some *define*  '1 month' to invariably be 30 days; that means Jan 31 + '1 month' ends up in March.